# CSS columns have a horizontal gap?

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I am having some issue trying to align css columns and a grid.
Do css columns have some horizontal gap by default? If so, how to configure it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But you can get rid of it by setting [`column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap) to `0`:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.grid>div {
  height: 40px;
}

.css-cols {
  columns: 4;
  column-gap:0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.css-cols li {
  height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.grid>div:nth-child(odd),
.css-cols li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black;
}

.grid>div:nth-child(even),
.css-cols li:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<ul class="css-cols">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

> The browser's default spacing is used between columns. For
>   multi-column layout this is specified as 1em.

Comment: Thanks! Just figured it out as well :)

Answer (score 0):

In this you can use the for column gap is

```
grid-column-gap
```

and for row you can use

```
grid-row-gap
```

and i suggest you use this shortcut key

```
grid-gap
```

this is for both row and column